# Incorrect syntax near delete expecting select or '('

Tags: sql

I'm trying to make a stored procedure, but I get this error   'incorrect syntax near delete expecting select or '(''

```
CREATE PROCEDURE NSP166_DeleteDMSPermission  
 @PermissionID uniqueidentifier  ,
 @FunctionalDetailsId uniqueidentifier
AS  
BEGIN  

if(SELECT count(PermissionID) AS counts FROM NSP166_RolePermissionTrans where PermissionID=@PermissionID)>1
(
delete from NSP166_RolePermissionTrans where FunctionalDetailsId=@FunctionalDetailsId
)END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for `if` does not use parentheses.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE NSP166_DeleteDMSPermission  
 @PermissionID uniqueidentifier  ,
 @FunctionalDetailsId uniqueidentifier
AS  
BEGIN  
    if (SELECT count(PermissionID) AS counts
        FROM NSP166_RolePermissionTrans
        where PermissionID=@PermissionID) > 1
    begin
        delete from NSP166_RolePermissionTrans
            where FunctionalDetailsId=@FunctionalDetailsId
    end
end;
```